# Execute stored mysql function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-functions

I have a mysql function (which works) that calculate the number of days between two dates discarding Saturdays and Sundays.
In **PHP** I call it like this:

```
$query=$this->conn->query("SELECT TOTAL_WEEKDAYS($start, $end) duration");
```

How can I save the result? I have tried

```
$row= $query->fetch();
$duration=$row['duration'];
```

But if I try to `echo $duration` it's empty.

Comment: Isn't the php command `mysql_fetch_row()`? Try that first.

Comment: @Mjh CALL is used for procedures; SELECT is correct.

Comment: @Parapluie if I try it, it says that mysql_fetch_row() is undefined

Comment: @AndreaRubi - correct, I'm having brain farts, thanks for correcting it :) On topic - are you checking whether your query succeeds or not? It appears as if you assume it executed fine.

Answer (score 0):

try `$query->fetch_assoc();`

like

```
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$duration = $row['duration'];

var_dump($duration, $row);
```